# Scrapy xpath returning more elements than it should

Tags: xpath, scrapy

I'm currently going thru a tutorial on Scrapy. Encountering the following issue when using xpath to filter out certain tag elements from an html file for example.

```
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Title of the page</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <h1>H1 Tag</h1>
            <h2>H2 Tag with <a href="#">link</a></h2>
            <p>First Paragraph</p>
            <p>Second Paragraph</p>
        </body> 
    </html>
```

The output for the line `response.xpath('/html/head/title').extract()` returned a list as such:

`['<title>Title of the page</title>\n    </head>\n    <body>\n        <h1>H1 Tag</h1>\n        <h2>H2 Tag with <a href="#">link</a></h2>\n   <p>First Paragraph</p>\n        <p>Second Paragraph</p>\n    </body>\n</html>\n']`.

It seems like it was able to start from the correct tag but it doesn't stop at the closing tag.  Using Visual Studio Code v.1.65.1. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you just want the title, try this ... `//title`

Answer (score 0):

As you have not provided links or specific HTML that you are trying to parse, it is not possible to reproduce the problem. You do not have a problem in this XPath or this HTML that you posted. See below my results:

```
In [1]: response.xpath('/html/head/title').extract()
Out[1]: ['<title>Title of the page</title>']
```

That being said, you have another problem that I am answering here.  `extract` always returns a list, even if there is only one match. The get the first match as string, the method is `extract_first`.

That's why Scrapy now recommends using `get` to get the first match as string, and `get_all` to get the list of strings. See the [docs here](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html#extract-and-extract-first).

Comment: `In [32]: body='<html><head><title>Title</title></head><body><p></p></body></html>'`
`In [33]: Selector(text=body).xpath('/html/head/title').get()`
`Out[33]: '<title>Title</title></head><body><p></p></body></html>\n' `                  I tried using `get` as suggested but seems to have similar result. It still pulls data after the `</title>` tag.

Comment: Problem appears to be fixed after reinstalling Anaconda and Scrapy.